# Modal teamplate as directive and use in parent component in angular 2

Tags: parent-child, angular-directive

in Util - I am having 
modal-dialog.component.ts

```
import {Component, Input, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef} from "@angular/core"; 
import {ModalDirective} from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap'; 

    @Component({
    selector: 'custom-modal',    
    templateUrl: 'modules/util/template/modal-dialog.html',
    exportAs: 'child' }) export class ModalDialogComponent {
    @ViewChild('childModal') public childModal: ModalDirective;
    public show(variant): void {
        debugger
        console.log(this.childModal);
        this.childModal.show();
    } }
```

modal-dialog.html

```
<div bsModal #childModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1"
role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Large modal</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> </div>
```

Util.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; 
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http'; 
import { ModalDialogComponent } from '../../util/components/modal-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        HttpModule,
        ModalModule        
    ],
    exports: [
        CommonModule,
    ],
    providers: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        ModalDialogComponent
    ] }) export class UtilModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {        
        return {
            ngModule: UtilModule
        };
    } }
```

app.module.ts

```
import UtilModule.forRoot()
```

test.component.html

```
<div>
   <custom-modal></custom-modal>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary (click)="c.show(variant)">open</button>
</div>
```

and in test.component.ts /* system-defined */

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, Directive, NgModule, ViewContainerRef} from '@angular/core'; 
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params  }  from '@angular/router';

@Component({           
    templateUrl: 'modules/sample/template/sample-test.component.html' })

export class SampleTestComponent {

}
```

I am unable to load child html on parent (test)

> Unhandled Promise
>       rejection: Template parse errors: 'custom-modal' is not a known
>       element:
>       1. If 'custom-modal' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
>       2. If 'custom-modal' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA" to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this
>       component to suppress this message. ("